# SQL Rank Function?

Tags: php, android, sql, rank

Hopefully this is the correct term for it.

Essentially i have a online sql database, php in the middle linking back to my android application

Columns are , User and Integer. It is sorted ascending so the highest integer first.

I would like it so that each user has a rank, ie the person at the top is 1, the person after 2, essentially the independent ascending list of numbers

What would be the best way to do this, would i have to add another row to the table, or could this function be achieved through sql / php queries

Comment: query by your autoincreament primary key using orderby ASC

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  In particular, what do you do with tied values?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `rownum` in your query, you don't need additional row:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT
    t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM
    users_table t,
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY
    t.`integer` DESC
```

**MSSQL & Oracle:**

```
SELECT
    t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.`integer` DESC) AS rank
FROM
    users_table t
ORDER BY
    t.`integer` DESC
```